# Understanding user-defined data types in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

i am trying to understand the architecture of PUBS Database sample by Microsoft
In there, I am looking at `au_id` Column, who has user-defined datatype **id:varchar(11)**.

So, if I understand clearly, varchar(11) means it allows to enter 11 characters in the cell. But if I enter

- 11 alphanumeric characters, it **gives error**.
- 11 numeric characters, it **gives error**
- But if I enter the characters in a US Telephone number format i.e. 123-54-2345, **it Works**
- Again, if I enter the dashes(hyphens) in some other order i.e. 1234-5-4544, **it again shows error**

Why does this happen ? Do they have some method to validate this entry. I can only find a user-defined datatype called `id` in the `User-Defined Data Type Folder`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking .....are you looking for a [beginner's tutorial on ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners) - or what??

Comment: are you really going to store 2 dashes in every row ? I surgest you use the datatype integer instead and drop the dashes.

Comment: *what* errors does it give? *usually*, error messages contain useful information to guide you towards the reason or a resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, just found the script that will create the pubs database.

The `au_id` column on authors is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
(
   au_id          id
     CHECK (au_id like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
     CONSTRAINT UPKCL_auidind PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  /* More columns */
```

It's the CHECK constraint that's rejecting your invalid values, rather than anything connected with the user-defined type. If you examine the error messages, it probably *mentions* that it's a `CHECK` constraint that's failing.

(BTW - I'd assumed that this was SSN format, not telephone numbers - anyone confirm?)

---

User defined types in SQL Server (other than table types) don't offer much value - all they really do is associated a shorthand name for a built-in type with all scale/precision/length options fixed.

They *would* be tremendously useful if the system would let you set up strict types - such that two values of the same underlying type, but with different type names, are not comparable/assignable - you'd get far better warnings/errors rather than queries proceding with mis-aligned joins, for example.